# Tensorflow Lite benchmark app explanation

Tags: tensorflow, benchmarking, tensorflow-lite

I'm using the [Tensorflow Lite Benchmark Android application](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/benchmark#parameters) to test my model on Android devices.
An example of the output is the following:

> Average inference timings in us: Warmup: 83235, Init: 38467, Inference: 79760.9

While the meaning `Inference` is quite clear to me (i.e., the average inference time in microseconds), I've no idea about what `Warmup` and `Init` refer to? Unfortunately, the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/measurement) does not explain this point.

Answer (score 0):

**Init**: The time it takes to load the model and build the interpreter object, which is the initialization step that needs to happen at the beginning (i.e., one-time cost)

**Warmup**: The average inference time it took for the warmup runs at the beginning, according to the `warmup_runs` configuration. In other words, the first `warmup_runs` number of inference results are averaged into the `Warmup` result in the output, and only the subsequent `num_runs` number of inferences are averaged into `Inference` output.

Take a look at the benchmark tool README for more details.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/tools/benchmark/README.md#parameters