# What do the Tensorflow Lite Benchmark tool's outputs mean

Tags: android, ios, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63705192/tensorflow-lite-benchmark-app-explanation).

The linked question asks about the inference time, warmup time and init time. I am specifically interested in "Memory usage during initialization time" and "Overall memory usage" that is mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/measurement). What memory is this referring to? And, what does "Overall memory usage" mean? Is this referring to the TOTAL memory it has allocated during the inferences it made?

If someone could give some specific details about these outputs, that would be extremely useful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

"Memory usage during initialization time" - The memory usage difference before/after creating a TFLite interpreter object in C++ and loading the model.

"Overall memory usage" - The memory usage difference before creating a TFLite interpreter object in C++ and loading the model and after running the benchmarking tasks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wanted to know more about the details of how a TFLite object is handled and how the interpreter allocates memory etc. I was wondering, could you point me to more detailed documentation regarding this? For example, I have used TensorRT in the past and the documentation of TensorRT is much more detailed - I am referring to the TensorRT developer guide which has a lot of information about how TensorRT works compared to the amount of information that is available about TFLite.

Comment: I also had another follow-up question. When talking about "Overall memory usage", what are the factors that go into this? Would it be things such as the memory to store the intermediate activations from a layer, memory to store the weights etc.? So in a simple sense, all the memory allocations made (such as through the use of "new" in C++ or malloc). 

These are the kinds of details I would be very interested in knowing.